# Does Drupal keep timestamps of every time node is updated

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm wondering whether Drupal keep tracks (keep timestamps) of every time a node is updated (not just the last updated). If it does, how could I access this in the front end?

Comment: I think you will only get these timestamps if you provide revisioning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Drupal stores the updated date, but for that you need to enable revisions on  the content types you need it. From your revision table, you can get when a node has been modfied. You can also get how many times you have created a revision and other revision details.

Check the node_revision table; you will get the details.

Comment: But do you know how to access the node revisions on the view?

Comment: Content revision: [field_name] In this way you can add the field on the view.

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK Also, a revision can be updated in place, so you won't necessarily see _all_  times a node had been updated.